# JQuery Inputmask not showing delimiters

Tags: jquery, masking, jquery-inputmask

I use RobinHerbots/Inputmask to mask an input field. Placeholder displays fine. But when I start to type in the input field delimiters disappear and the text is unmasked.

```
  $(function() {
      $('#my_id').inputmask("**-**-****-****",
      {placeholder:"X", 
      clearMaskOnLostFocus: false });
    });


    <input type="text" id="my_id" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnedg7wo/

How to make the dashes stay?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do it another way, but still same issue: dashes disappear once I start typing in the field. $(document).ready(function(){
Inputmask.extendAliases();
Inputmask.extendAliases({"custom": {"alias":"**-**-****-****"}}); 
jQuery('#my_id').inputmask("custom");
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the GitHub URLs for the latest 4.x script sources... And I see a commit 4 days ago [here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). I can't tell if that is directly related. But why not use the stable 3.3.4 bundle avalaible on cdnjs?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my_id').inputmask("**-**-****-****",{
    placeholder:"X", 
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="my_id" />
```

Comment: Using a  3.3.4 bundle fixed the issue! Thank you!